# Make a call to a function including an ID of an element in order to display his information

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an Organizational Chart which looks like this so far

[image]

every person in that template has an `id`, when you click on any of the persons there, you will see a sidebar at the right side like this

[image]

and obviously the information on that sidebar, should be the information of the person/node you clicked on in order to open the sidebar.

For example:

In the first image, the third person/node is from a guy named Jorge Lopez with Project Manager as a title, if you click on that person, the sidebar will come up and the info you should see on the sidebar should be the rest of the information about Jorge Lopez which is the person you clicked.

I will show you the code I have so far:

*Just in case: I am using Handlebars and jQuery.

Here is just a little part of the JSON I am using within a file named `chart-container.json`

```
  {
    "enterprise" : [
      {
        "id" : "10",
        "name" : "Hellen Quesada",
        "role" : "Principal Software Engineer",
        "image" : "/image.url",
        "employeeN" : "46456456"
      },
      {
        "id" : "11",
        "name" : "Jonathan Chavez",
        "role" : "Principal Creative Engineer",
        "image" : "/image.url",
        "employeeN" : "46456456"
      },
      {
        "id" : "12",
        "name" : "Rodrigo Ovares",
        "role" : "Creative Engineer",
        "image" : "/image.url",
        "employeeN" : "46456456"
      }
    ]
  }
```

and here the way I am rendering it with Handlebars

```
{{#each chart-container.[0].enterprise}}
    <li class="section">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="name-role">
                <div>{{image}}</div>
                {{name}} <br> {{role}}
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

here is the sidebar HTML with the hardcoded data

```
<div class="personal-card" data-action="personalCard">
    <div id="sidebar">

        <div class="card-bg">
            <img src="http://img.url" />
        </div>

        <div class="arrow-box">
        <div class="arrow dir-two"></div>
      </div>

        <div class="personal-info">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="name-role">
                        <span>
                            <img class="card-picture"
                                     src="https://img.url" />
                        </span>

                        <div class="main-info-card">
                            Marcelo Retana <br>
                            Frontend Engineer <br>
                            Employee N.32423523
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </li>
            <li><p>Email: <strong>myemail@theemail.com</strong></p></li>
            <li><p>Skype: <strong>myskype</strong></p></li>
            <li><p class="team">Digitas, Flag <br> <strong>Enterprise</strong></p></li>
            <li><strong>Offshore: Costa Rica</strong></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here the way I am calling the sidebar

```
  $(function() {
    var s = 0;

    $('#sidebar .arrow-box, .client-director').click(function() {
        console.log(s);
        if (s === 0) {
            s = 1;
            $('#sidebar').css('left', '0');
            $('#sidebar .arrow').removeClass('dir-two');
            $('#sidebar .arrow').addClass('dir-one');
            $('#content').css('padding-left', '0');
        } else {
            s = 0;
            $('#sidebar').css('left', '-300px');
            $('#sidebar .arrow').addClass('dir-two');
            $('#sidebar .arrow').removeClass('dir-one');
            $('#content').css('padding-left', '300px');
        }
    });
  });
```

so, at this point, if its clear for you, what can I do in order to call the sidebar with the proper information about the html node you just clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your template to have:

```
<a href="#{{employeeN}}">
```

you could then get their `employeeN` in your sidebar call from the click handler itself like:

```
$('#sidebar .arrow-box, .client-director').click(function(evt) {
    var employeeN = evt.target.href
```

and use that to get your employee info